# Syntax Error - Map multidimensional array in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been scratching my head for hours trying to figure out why do I get a syntax error when trying to iterate a multidimensional array :

```
const InputPanel = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const { board } = this.props;

    return(      
      <br />
      {board.map(rows => {
        rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>); 
      })
    }
  );

 }
});
```

CodePen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXgmrR

I tried to add\modify parenthesis types and nothing helps.

Here is the view i'm trying to produce:

```
</br>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
</br>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
</br>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
<div className="digit">1</div>
```

Comment: You can't have mutliple root nodes.  Try wrap your return with a <div>.

Comment: Here is an example of multi dimensional array rendering: http://www.webpackbin.com/NkFV9a23b

Comment: @ctrlplusb I've modified my code. can you please tell me why I'm getting only one cube ? 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXgmrR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code.

1. Your `rows.map(...)` statement isn't actually outputting anything. You need to `return` the result of `rows.map` to have it rendered.

You could do this:

```
{board.map(rows => {
        return rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>); 
    })
}
```

or this:

```
{board.map(rows => rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>))}
```

2. It's not clear to me if `this` in the `render` method will actually reference the component. I usually use [ES2015 classes or stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) to create my components, simply because the logic seems clearer to me.

So, your component could be rewritten:

```
class InputPanel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { board } = this.props;

        return(
            <br />
            {board.map(rows =>
                    rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>)
                )
            }
        );

    }
}
```

or, even more simply:

```
const InputPanel = ({ board }) =>  (
    <br />
    {board.map(rows => rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>))}
);
```

Now, I could be wrong about `this` - like I said, I'm not that familiar with the `React.createClass` way of doing things.

3. React is not going to like that bare `<br />` in your component. `render` methods need to return a single element, so you're going to need to wrap everything in your `render` method in a `<div>` or some other element.

And **this final one is the source of your syntax error**: without that wrapping element, Javascript (or more accurately whatever system you're using to interpret JSX code) sees something like this:

```
return (
    { /* some Javascript code here */ }
);
```

which is not valid Javascript - you can't just return a code block like that.

With an enclosing `<div>`, the code looks like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        { /* some Javascript code here */ }
    </div>
);
```

which **is** valid JSX code and your JSX preprocessor can parse it.

So, to wrap it all up, the simplest form of your component would look something like this:

```
const InputPanel = ({ board }) =>  (
    <div>
        {board.map(rows => rows.map(cell => <div className="digit">1</div>))}
    </div>
);
```

As an aside, I'd recommend looking into [eslint](http://eslint.org/) to lint your code & catch errors like this. I try to use it religiously and I like to think it has improved my code quality :-)

Comment: Thanks !!! Great explanation ! You've cleared many things for me!
Just one question regarding your 3rd paragraph :
Should I modify my code to something like:
 return(
            {board.map(rows =>
                    </InputCell><br />
                )
            }
        );

Comment: can you tell me why I'm still getting a single element ? 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXgmrR

Comment: Because (at least in the codepen you linked to) you're not actually using `InputPanel` anywhere. Look at your `App` component` - it's rendering a single `div`

Comment: fixed it. And now I doesn't get anything.

Comment: I've also added "return" before the last map

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to debug your code. One thing I do notice is that your `mapStateToProps` function doesn't do anything - perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

for react native had an issue where I was all ready doing a map iteration 
but had one key that was an object i was doing something like:

```
{this.state.some_data.map(item => (
  <View style={styles.row} key={item.product_id}>
    <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
    // BUT item.variations_json IS a multi dimential object ???
  </View>
))}
```

The Solution for me was ..

```
  render() {
    //...
  const someVariation = (variation, product_id) => {
    var vdata = [];
    Object.entries(variation.data).map(([key,v]) => {
      vdata.push(
        <View key={key}>
          <Text >{v.sku}</Text>
          <Text >{v.title}</Text>
          <Text>{v.price}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
   return vdata;
  };
//...
```

then Later

```
  {this.state.some_data.map(item => (
   <View style={styles.row} key={item.product_id}>
   <Text style={styles.header}>{item.title}</Text>
   <someVariation data={item.variations_json} id={item.product_id}></someVariation>
    </View>
   ))}
```